# Getting an error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method setEntity(HttpEntity) from the type HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase"

Tags: android, spreadsheet, http-request

I'm creating an activity of an android app where the user fills his details (identified by id's name, bhawan, room, mobile, books etc) and these values are to be transferred directly to the Google spreadsheet. It gives me that weird error. Can you help me out ? Thanks in advance.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    final EditText nameField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextName);  
    String name = nameField.getText().toString(); 

    final EditText bhawanField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextBhawan);  
    String bhawan = bhawanField.getText().toString();

    final EditText roomField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextRoom);  
    String room = roomField.getText().toString();

    final EditText mobileField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextPhone);  
    String mobile = mobileField.getText().toString();

    final EditText emailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextEmail);  
    String email = emailField.getText().toString();

    final EditText bookField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditTextBook);  
    String book = bookField.getText().toString();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);         

        Button sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ButtonSubmit);
        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
            public void onClick(View v) {
                btn_Click();
            }}
        );
    }   

    public void btn_Click(){
         SendHttpRequset();       
    }

     public void SendHttpRequset(){
         HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?hl=en_US&amp;formkey=dDlwZzh4bGFvNFBxUmRsR0d2VTVhYnc6MQ&amp;ifq");

            List<BasicNameValuePair> results = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>(6);
            results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.0.single", name));
            results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.1.single", bhawan));
            results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.2.single", room));
            results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.4.single", mobile));
            results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.6.single", email));
            results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.8.single", book));

            try {
                HttpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(results));
            }
            catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                // writing error to Log
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Making HTTP Request
            try {
                HttpResponse response = HttpClient.execute(post);

                // writing response to log
                Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // writing exception to log
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // writing exception to log
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
     }

    /*public void submitDetails() {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://spreadsheets.google.com/spreadsheet/formResponse?hl=en_US&amp;formkey=dDlwZzh4bGFvNFBxUmRsR0d2VTVhYnc6MQ&amp;ifq");

        List<BasicNameValuePair> results = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>(6);
        results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.0.single", name));
        results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.1.single", bhawan));
        results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.2.single", room));
        results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.4.single", mobile));
        results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.6.single", email));
        results.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entry.8.single", book));

        try {
            HttpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(results));
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // writing error to Log
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Making HTTP Request
        try {
            HttpResponse response = HttpClient.execute(post);

            // writing response to log
            Log.d("Http Response:", response.toString());

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // writing exception to log
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try changing:

```
HttpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(results));
```

to

```
post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(results));
```

You were previously calling setEntity() in a way used to call static functions, when it is not a static method. Your probably meant to call it using the `post` object you created earlier.

Answer (score 0):

HttpPost is a static class, but setEntity() is a non-static method. To call non-static method, you need to instantiate an instance of the class, e.g., myHttpPost, using the `new` keyword, or another method provided by the class.